# Consulting agreement between my corporation and client also includes me individually

Tags: contract-law, software, contractor

I own a Canadian corporation, which consults on software. Recently, I've been offered a contract with a US company. Instead of making the contract solely with my company, it states that "Consultant" is comprised both of my company, and myself individually: `Bob Smith, an individual, and Bob's Software Company, Inc. ( together “Consultant”)`

The NDA portion is directed at my person, and obviously all the legal responsibilities would also involve my person, not just the corporation.

Is this a usual practice? Is it something to be wary of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that it makes you and your company liable for the obligations of the contract. If something goes wrong and your client wants to sue you, they can sue either or both people - putting your personal assets (home, car etc.) at risk as well as the assets of your company.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that it's a form contract and they just plug and play the names. If there are parts of the contract that you don't like, or you want spelled out better, ask for it. Hopefully you have an attorney reviewing it on your behalf - it may cost you a little money, but it would certainly be worth it if things went poorly.